# Change the notify js plug-in auto hide delay time

Tags: javascript, jquery, notify

my example is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        {% for label, messages in app.session.flashbag.all %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                $.notify('{{message|trans}}', '{{label}}', [{autoHideDelay : 20000}]);
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        $('input[type="date"]').attr('type', 'text');
    });
```

The message dissapear after 5 sec because in notify.js autoHideDelay is 5000. How can I change that from html template. Because like I show you not work. Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the working example with long duration notify for **20000 ms (20 sec)** using **autoHideDelay** option

```js
$(function(){
  var successOptions = {
      autoHideDelay: 20000,
      showAnimation: "fadeIn",
      hideAnimation: "fadeOut",
      hideDuration: 700,
      arrowShow: false,
      className: "success",
  };

  $("#btnSuccess").on("click", function () {
     $.notify("Success message!", successOptions);
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/notifyjs/notifyjs/master/dist/notify.js"></script>
<button id="btnSuccess">Display Success</button>
```